# Perform Sum In Update Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am trying to run this update statement, but it keeps giving me the error of

> (3 row(s) affected)
>   Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

What do I need to do diff in order to be able to have the sum added to the second field?

```
Create Table #ABCD
(
  time1 decimal(16,4)
  ,time2 decimal(16,4)
)
Insert Into #ABCD(time1) Values
('12.01'), ('13.04'), ('22.22')

Update #ABCD
SET time2 = SUM(time1/60/60)
```

Comment: The SUM of what? What should the values of `time2` be?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - the value of time2 should be the sum of time1/60/60

Comment: So, for row with `time1=12.01`, the value of `time2` should be `12.01 / 60 / 60`? And for row with `time1=13.04`, the value of `time2` should be `13.04 / 60 / 60`?

Comment: Okay bad example, I see what you are saying...

Comment: Why do you need the #temp table to *store* this calculation? And should it really get the aggregate for the whole table into every single row? Why? Why not just store this in a variable, or calculate it during subsequent queries?

Comment: You want to add the sum of all rows divided by 3600? Do you need to update it when you add another row or update an existing? That's bad, better go for a WIndowed Aggregate: `SELECT SUM(time1) OVER ()/60/60 AS time2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to calculate the aggregate inside a CTE ([I blogged about this last month](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-ctes)):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT time1, time2, t2 = SUM(time1) OVER()
  FROM #abcd
)
UPDATE CTE SET time2 = t2/60/60;
```

But I don't understand the value of putting the same SUM(), aggregated over the whole table, into that column for *every single row*. Seems easier to just store this single value in a variable, or calculate it at runtime (just use the query inside the CTE).